# How to use attachment_id from new Upload API?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

According the docs for the Messenger Platform 1.4, the Upload API returns an attachment_id for the uploaded attachment:

```
{
   "attachment_id":"1854626884821032"
}
```

How do we use this attachment_id to send attachments? Or does simply sending another message with an attachment from the same URL result in messenger using the uploaded attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$imageAttachment = array('type' => 'image'``, 'payload' =>   array('attachment_id' =>  '1854626884821032'));

$params = array('message' => array('attachment' => $imageAttachment), "recipient" => array("id" => $senderId));
```

and the make a Curl as specified here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment

Comment: When you post a link as a support please post a sample of code that can resolve the problem and then backed with a link.